# Adding array to array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

I have an array from CSV import. The array look like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [DOCategory] => IM
            [ToCustomerCode] => M-CBC
            [ExternalDocNo] => DRDOC-DJ-GBAR10-25
            [Item] => S160373
            [Quantity] => 4
            [Remark2] => TEST
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [DOCategory] => IM
            [ToCustomerCode] => M-CBD
            [ExternalDocNo] => DRDOC-DJ-GBAR10-25
            [Item] => S160373
            [Quantity] => 5
            [Remark2] => TEST2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [DOCategory] => IM
            [ToCustomerCode] => M-CJ
            [ExternalDocNo] => DRDOC-DJ-GBAR10-25
            [Item] => S160373
            [Quantity] => 5
            [Remark2] => TEST3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [DOCategory] => IM
            [ToCustomerCode] => M-CL
            [ExternalDocNo] => DRDOC-DJ-GBAR10-25
            [Item] => S160373
            [Quantity] => 4
            [Remark2] => TEST4
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [DOCategory] => IM
            [ToCustomerCode] => M-CRG
            [ExternalDocNo] => DRDOC-DJ-GBAR10-25
            [Item] => S160373
            [Quantity] => 4
            [Remark2] => TEST5
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [DOCategory] => IM
            [ToCustomerCode] => M-CRGM
            [ExternalDocNo] => DRDOC-DJ-GBAR10-25
            [Item] => S160373
            [Quantity] => 4
            [Remark2] => TEST6
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [DOCategory] => IM
            [ToCustomerCode] => M-CRSB
            [ExternalDocNo] => DRDOC-DJ-GBAR10-25
            [Item] => S160373
            [Quantity] => 4
            [Remark2] => TEST7
        )

)
```

But now i want to add a session. So My Array will look loke this.

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [DOCategory] => IM
            [ToCustomerCode] => M-CBC
            [ExternalDocNo] => DRDOC-DJ-GBAR10-25
            [Item] => S160373
            [Quantity] => 4
            [Remark2] => TEST
            [session] => ....
        )
```

The `[session]` is from this

```
$random = md5(uniqid( $userlogin, true));
$new = array('session' => $random);
```

Then Here is what i try so far

```
 $x=0;
                    while( ($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
                        $data[] = $line;
                    }
                    for($x=0;$x<count($data);$x++){
                        if($x != 0) {
                            $newArray[] = array_combine($data[0], $data[$x]);
                            $newArrays[] = $new;
                        }
                    }
                $newArray = array_push($newArray,$newArrays);
                echo "<pre>";print_r($newArray);
```

and the result from my `echo "<pre>";print_r($newArray);` is `8`. So how can i achieve that i want. Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Why not just use a for or foreach statement to iterate through the array and add the session key/value?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is strange, but try this:

```
$x=0;
while( ($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
   $data[] = $line;
}
for($x=0;$x<count($data);$x++){
   if($x != 0) {
       $newArray[] = array_combine($data[0], $data[$x]);
       $newArray[$x]["session"] = $new;
   }
}
echo "<pre>";print_r($newArray);
```

you can also skip the temp array if you don't need it:

```
$x=0;
while( ($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
   $data[] = $line;
}
for($x=0;$x<count($data);$x++){
   if($x != 0) {
       $data[$x]["session"] = $new;
   }
}
echo "<pre>";print_r($data);
```

Comment: I still need this part ` $newArray[] = array_combine($data[0], $data[$x]);`

Comment: ok, so just add the array to it on the next line. `$newArray[$x]["session"] = $new;`

Answer (score 1):

You use this function

```html
   $arr1= array_merge($arr1, $arr2);
```

Comment: It gime like this   `[6] => Array
        (
            [DOCategory] => IM
            [ToCustomerCode] => M-CRSB
            [ExternalDocNo] => DRDOC-DJ-GBAR10-25
            [Item] => S160373
            [Quantity] => 4
            [Remark2] => TEST7
        )

    [session] => e3ba1d241080830f2638be5a91debd69`

Comment: please say more clear about the trouble, I m using mobile web , so I cant see clearly

Answer (score 0):

Loop over your array and add a session index

```
for($x=0;$x<count($data);$x++)
    {
     $newArrays[$x]['session'] = $new;
    }
```

Comment: I answered this first :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_walk](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php)

**Try this**

```
array_walk($array, function(&$a) {
  $a['session'] = md5(uniqid( $userlogin, true));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use php array function `array_merge()` [Here is link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

Answer (score 0):

use `array_map()` or foreach or array_walk to itereate and add session key.

```
array_map(function($v){
  $v['session'] = md5(uniqid( $userlogin, true));
  return $v;
});
```